# Showing a video in a VideoView by its URL

Tags: java, android, aide-ide

I am trying to load a video in VideoView in my app but when I open it,  it says that it can't play this video. 
This is my code:

```
video=findViewById(R.id.mainVideoView);                     

    Uri uri = Uri.parse("https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://m.youtube.com/watch%3Fv%3DlLVrP_nzvB8&ved=2ahUKEwjjxtCQ_abgAhVUuXEKHTdUAggQwqsBMAR6BAgHEAU&usg=AOvVaw29VZ4OKcAgFXwyBjLjgTcN");
    video.setVideoURI(uri);
    MediaController mc = new MediaController(MainActivity.this);
    video.setMediaController(mc);
    video.requestFocus();
    video.start();
```

Comment: if you want to show YouTube video means, first integrate YouTube on your app, then pass URL like (" lLVrP_nzvB8 " this is your above given YouTube link ) .

Answer (score 0):

you can't play youtube videos by using **videoView** as you mention in your question. kindly use this library, that allows you to play youtube videos in your android app. [youtube_android_player_api](https://developers.google.com/youtube/android/player/)